# Error with custom iterator and STL Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator

I am working on a custom iterator for my linear algebra library. I have the following code (slight modification of http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/)

```
template<class T, std::size_t Increment = 1>
class iter: public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>{   
private:
    T* m_pter;

public:

    iter(T* value):  m_pter(value){}
    iter(const iter& other_it): m_pter(other_it.m_pter){}
    iter& operator++() { m_pter+=Increment; return *this; }
    // iter& operator+() { m_pter += Increment; return *this; }
    bool operator!=(const iter& rhs) {return m_pter!=rhs.m_pter;}
    bool operator<(const iter& rhs) {return m_pter<rhs.m_pter;}
    T& operator*() { return *m_pter; }
};
```

in the main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

     std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
     iter<int, 2> from( &a[0] );
     iter<int, 2> to( &a[8] + 1 );
     for(;from < to;++from){std::cout << *from << std::endl;}
     // std::for_each(from, to, [](int i){std::cout << i << " ";});
     std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

returns:
    $ ./main
    1 3 5 7 9

which is exactly what I want. However using std::for_each... version returns:

```
$ ./main
1 3 5 7 9 135121 0 0 many zeros ...
```

I have no idea why the std algorithm "jumps over" my last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::for_each` use `!=` but as you have an odd number of element, you never reach the equality.

You have the same error if you replace your loop

```
for(; from < to; ++from)
```

by

```
for(;from != to;++from)
```

Comment: You are right. iter<int,2> to( &a[8] + 2 ); Actually did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a lot more functions if you declare the
iterator as random access: all of the comparison operators,
pre- and post-fix `++` and `--`, `+=`, `-=`, `+` and `-` with an
integral type, and `-` between to iterators.

But that's not the immediate problem.  The imediate problem is
that the universally used end condition is `==`, and that in
a striding iterator, you have to protect against going beyond
one past the end.  Practically speaking, this means that you
need two pointers, one at the current position, and one one past
the end, and you need something like:

```
Iter& operator+=( ptrdiff_t n )
{
    m_current = std::min( m_end - m_current, n * stride );
    return *this;
}
```

Worse: to support subtraction from one past the end, you need to
work out how much you would have incremented to get there, which
means either keeping track of the last increment, or keeping
the pointer passed to the iterator as well.

You might want to look at the hoops Boost jumps through in its
`filter_iterator`.  (In the end, a striding iterator is just
a special case of a filtering iterator.)  It's not pretty, but
it's about the best you can do given the way C++ defines
iterators.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kanze. Indeed this is simplified version of the final iterator class. Indeed you are absolutely right: ensuring the iterator does not go end in undefined behaviour is the key issue to ensure proper implementation of the class. However I must also say, compared to a previous version I had (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314541/c-speed-comparison-iterator-vs-index) the performance gain is astonishing. So I am confident that I am on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try providing `operator==()`?

I'd think that this is the one used by `std::foreach()`

Comment: ...    bool operator==(const iter& rhs) {return m_pter==rhs.m_pter;}... same result.